# Move or copy file client side - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a classic asp page with a bog standard HTML form with a file element (`<input type="file" name="file" />`). I want the user to browse and select the file then on the next page the file will be copied client side to another location.

I have done some research and found JavaScript might work and am using the following code.

```
fileupload = request.form("file")
if fileupload = "" then
else%>
<script type="text/javascript">
function moveFile(){
   var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   var file = object.GetFile("Z:\\Test.txt");
   file.Move("\\soc\info\Engineering\");
   document.write("File is moved successfully");
}
</script>
<%end if%>
```

The test file did not copy.
How do I get this working and how do I pass the fileupload file into the javascript?

Comment: Caution: ActiveXObject is only supported by IE and not by any other browser. 

Javascript doesn't support client side file manipulation. 

What you are talking is a very big Hazard if websites are allowed to do so. Imagine You open a website and deletes all the files on your system(Bcoz moving is somewhat like that only).

Comment: What you CAN do is upload the file using file element, and then download that file using the browser, but you CAN'T manipulate user's file system directly.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any example code to do this ? From what I understand i'll need a component to do this ?

Comment: You can't control where the file would be downloaded to though. If you want to do anything like this, then you should probably consider not trying to do it through a web browser.